# What does -h in lambda (h, t): (-h, t) do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Here is the entire function:

```
def dailyTemperatures( temperatures):
   queue = []
   for p in sorted(temperatures, key=lambda (h, t): (-h, t)):
       print (p[1])
       queue.insert(p[1], p)
   return queue
```

input:

```
[[7,0], [4,4], [7,1], [5,0], [6,1], [5,2]]
```

output:

```
[[5,0], [7,0], [5,2], [6,1], [4,4], [7,1]]
```

I know that lambda is a constructor that creates an anonymous function. In this anonymous function `h` and `t` are passed as parameters. What happens to `h`  when it becomes `-h`?

Comment: The same thing that usually happens when you apply a negative sign to something.

Comment: so in this case if we take the first item in the input: ` [7,0]` does it become [-7,0]?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lambda (h, t): (-h, t)` is utilizing tuple paramater unpacking, which is available in Python2 only. It is a more Pythonic alternative to `lambda x:(-x[0], x[-1])`. The negative sign is functioning as you would expect with any value when multiplied by negative one i.e the resulting value is the absolute value reflected across the "number line", thus negating the original value. The unpacking takes the first and second values of the list passed to the function and applies the negative sign to the first.

Comment: To further put this into context, this lambda is a key for the `sorted()` function, which causes the tuples in the list, list to be sorted in descending order by their first element, then, where there is more than one tuple with equal first elements, in ascending order by the second element.

Answer (score 0):

As you specify a lambda function as `key`, a tuple, which is an element of list, will be sent to the lambda function in this case.

```
key=lambda (h, t): (-h, t)
```

Usually in the lambda expression we pick a vlue from the tuple as a key to compare, but the code you showed above just **negate the first value in the tuple**, and remain the tuple itself as a key.